# Application Insights TraceListener: Setting Severity level

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, trace-listener

The answer to this might be a simple no, but I was wanting to set the severity level of the Trace events that are reported.

I am using the prerelease versions of the Application Insights API and Application Insights TraceListener.

Basically I just want to filter out Trace events with a verbose severity. I know I can filter them out when viewing the Application insights in the Azure portal, but I would rather them not be reported at all. Is there a way to set the severity level of Trace Events for application Insights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known limitation that if you add application insights listener under "listeners" tag in your config filters will not work.
But if you add it under [shared listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a filter it should work.