# Priority Setup For Application Insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Currently, I am working on Telemetry client. I want to set the priority level at the code level. Can Someone help me to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that Application Insight has not been able to set a priority level for the traced events so far. The client apps send synthetic requests to the web service, Application Insight works like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview#how-does-application-insights-work).

This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/18022885-add-a-priority-level-for-all-traced-events), you could vote it. Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651841/application-insights-tracelistener-setting-severity-level), you could refer to it.